# how can i convert 2 different kind date

Tags: c#, sql

How can I convert 2 different kinds of date: I used `>=` like this:

```
(DateTime.Parse(i.ACTUAL_FIT_DATE) >=  txtboxFromDate.Text
```

but I have error

User enter string like this `txtboxFromDate.Text`
And I want compare it with database `DateTime` value like this: `i.ACTUAL_FIT_DATE`

What should I do?

Comment: you can use parse like you did with the string from the db.. and you might want to look at this for the comparison: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert the string to date like this:

```
DateTime inputDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtboxFromDate.Text);
```

And compare them as you did before:

```
i.ACTUAL_FIT_DATE >= inputDate
```

if you want to compare dates, and not the time

```
i.ACTUAL_FIT_DATE.Date >= inputDate.Date
```

Comment: i have 30000 record and this convert date code take many time and hang and did not complete...how can i use a code that take few time?tanks

Comment: I don't think so that the convert of 30000 record takes more than some micro second. You can try a console sample app where you create a list with 30000 dates as a string and convert them back to dates. You will see the result.